# Calling async functions recursively

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I need to have an async method eg. `getWeather` called forever with a small delay between the success of previous call and beginning of the next call. I have used a recursive function for the purpose. I am concerned if this can cause a performance hit. Are there any better ways to do this?

```
var request = require('request');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var delayTwoSecs = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
};

var getWeather = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request({
            method: 'GET',
            uri: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139'
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(body)
            }
        });
    });
};

var loopFetching = function() {
    getWeather()
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            return delayTwoSecs();
        }).then(function(response) {
            loopFetching();
        });
};

loopFetching();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need the `delayTwoSecs` function, you can use the [`Promise.delay`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#delayint-ms---promise) function.
2. Instead of `getWeather`, you can use the `bluebird` to [`Promisify`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) all the functions and use the proper function, in this case `getAsync`, directly.

So, your program becomes like this

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));
var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139';

(function loopFetching() {
    request.getAsync(url)
         // We get the first element from the response array with `.get(0)`
        .get(0)
         // and the `body` property with `.get("body")`
        .get("body")
        .then(console.log.bind(console))
        .delay(2000)
        .then(loopFetching)
        .catch(console.err.bind(console));
})();
```

This is called [Immediately Invoking Function Expression.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/1903116)

Comment: This is functionally and peformance-wise same as the code in the question right?

Comment: @Cyril I don't see any reason to be concerned about performance in either approach.

Comment: You can change `.then(function(response){ response[0].body }` with `.get(0).get("body").then(function(body){ ...` Also - might as well chain promises.

Answer (score -1):

### setInterval() for recurring requests

You're over-complicating it with nested calls. Use setInterval() instead.

```
var request = require('request');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var getWeather = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request({
            method: 'GET',
            uri: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139'
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(body)
            }
        });
    });
};

var my_interval = setInterval("getWeather()",2000);
```

Comment: I needed the next call to be initiated only if the previous call was successful. And I also need to make sure the there is a constant delay in the interim. setInterval won't take care of the above two cases I guess..

Comment: Oh my. Why are you using a string in `setInterval()`?

Comment: @JSRishe have you ever tried to build a `setInterval()` command dynamically? That is how you do it.

Comment: @FactoryAidan: No it's not. I doubt this even works, as `getWeather` is not global in node.js.